# how to design layouts at runtime in android

Tags: android, layout

I want to design a layout with 4 buttons to align in a square format.

Eg:

```
       1     2

       3     4
```

Answer (score 0):

(This is for example change accordingly your need)

In your Activity..

```
this.setContentView(R.layout.main);

      /* Find Tablelayout defined in main.xml */
      TableLayout tl = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.myTableLayout);
           /* Create a new row to be added. */
           TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
           tr.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                          LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                          LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                /* Create a Button to be the row-content. */
                Button b = new Button(this);
                b.setText("Dynamic Button");
                b.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                          LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                          LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                /* Add Button to row. */
                tr.addView(b);
      /* Add row to TableLayout. */
      tl.addView(tr,new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

And this is your **main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/myTableLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
     <TableRow
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content">

          <Button android:text="Static Button"/>
     </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Comment: i'am not getting my display!! it shows no error but still. i did setContentView(linearlayout); still it is nt showing me the output

Comment: TableRow tr3 = new TableRow(this);
        tr3.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
   tl.addView(tr3, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
             
             setContentView(ll);
             Button btnSearch = new Button(this);
             btnSearch.setText("Search");
             btnSearch.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
             
             tr3.addView(btnSearch);

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="78dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="154dp"
        android:text="@string/button_1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="53dp"
        android:text="@string/button_2" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_marginTop="59dp"
        android:text="@string/button_3" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button2"
        android:text="@string/button_4" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use GridView for this case,please refer the link
http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gridview.html